# SPARQL Aggregate function SUM with GROUP BY error

Tags: datetime, group-by, sum, aggregate, sparql

I am working with a database describing membership of the ANDB database (General Dutch Diamond Worker Database) using SPARQL on Druid, which is a triplestore for historical data. I want to show membership over time for each sex, using starting dates on the members membership cards. In my attempts, I was able to show general membership for each day over time. Yet I have not been able to do this per year.

Using some filters and the Year function, I was able to convert the dates to year, leaving multiple rows per year. I need to add these together to get one row for each year, with for each year the sum of the rows now for each year. But I am not succeeding.

I havent even been able to consider sex/gender yet, one problem at the time I guess.

I made the following SPARQL query thus far, showing multiple counts per year.

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX time: <http://w3.org/2006/time#> 
PREFIX schema: <https://schema.org> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX vocab: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/adb-andb> 
PREFIX org: <http://w3.org/ns/org#>

#selecting a count of starting memberships per day and converting xsd:date to a year
SELECT (YEAR(xsd:dateTime(?Startdate)) as ?Startyear) (COUNT(?People) as ?N)
WHERE {
  ?People rdf:type schema:Person;
          org:hasMembership/org:memberDuring/time:hasBeginning/time:inXSDDate ?Startdate;
#filters to make YEAR function work, some string dates in the database will not convert to xsd:dateTime as they do not exist as valid dates.
  FILTER(!REGEX(?Startdate, '\\d{4}-[0][0]-\\d\\d'))
  FILTER(!REGEX(?Startdate, '\\d{4}-\\d\\d-[0][0]'))
  FILTER(!REGEX(?Startdate, "0000"))
  FILTER(!REGEX(?Startdate, "04-31"))
}
ORDER BY ?Startyear
```

Here is a sneak peak for the result:
[Result of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Ksm.png)

I tried to GROUP BY ?Startyear and making a SUM of the COUNT in the SELECT part of the code, but I just receive errors.

Comment: binding the year inside the query would allow to group by it, then you can just use the `count` aggregate function as is: `SELECT ?Startyear  (COUNT(?People) as ?N) WHERE { ... FILTER(!REGEX(?Startdate, "04-31")) BIND(YEAR(xsd:dateTime(?Startdate) as ?Startyear) } GROUP BY ?Startyear`

Comment: Binding on @UninformedUser's comment

You can put the YEAR-AS in the `GROUP BY` itself:
`SELECT ?Startyear (COUNT(?People) as ?N)
...
GROUP BY ( YEAR(xsd:dateTime(?Startdate)) as ?Startyear)
ORDER BY ?Startyear
`